# Como associar campos do datatable as colunas do DataGridView?

Tags: winforms, vb.net, datagridview

Meu problema é seguinte, eu faço uma consulta no banco que me retorna um datatable com grande variedade de campos. O Objetivo é exibir essa consulta no datagridview, entretanto, exibindo apenas alguns dos campos do datatable.

Eu tinha um código anterior aqui, mas ele simplesmente deixou de funcionar.

*Vou descrever o processo:*

- 1º Realiza Busca no Banco e Retorna Datatable Preenchido
- 2º Cria colunas no datagridview e as associa aos campos do Datatable

  ```
  With DgvErros
      .ColumnCount = 2
      .AutoGenerateColumns = False
      .Columns(0).Name = "Codigo_Produto"
      .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "Codigo_Produto"
      .Columns(1).Name = "Descricao"
      .Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "Descricao"
      .DataSource = Bs
      .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
  End With
  ```

Na minha consulta, eu tenho o campo "**Codigo_Produto**"... mas o programa dispara um erro ao chegar na parte em que ele da um nome a coluna 0 do DataGridView.

Erro : "Não é possível definir a propriedade ColumnCount em um controle DataGridView limitado por dados."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse forma irá ocasionar um erro na próxima pesquisa, logo, na entrada ele dará certo após isso ele vai dar um erro porque as colunas já estão presentes ... então, faça a rotina de configuração separada, da de atualização ...

Exemplo:

```
Private Sub Configurar_GridView()
    With DgvErros
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .AutoGenerateColumns = False
        .Columns(0).Name = "Codigo_Produto"
        .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "Codigo_Produto"
        .Columns(1).Name = "Descricao"
        .Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "Descricao"
        .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
        .AllowUserToAddRows = False
        .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
        .AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
        .AllowUserToResizeColumns = False
        .AllowUserToResizeRows = False
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Executar_Pesquisa()
    Dim Bs = New DataTable("Bs")
    Bs.Columns.Add("Codigo_Produto")
    Bs.Columns.Add("Descricao")
    Dim Row = Bs.NewRow()
    Row("Codigo_Produto") = 1
    Row("Descricao") = "Nome 1"

    Bs.Rows.Add(Row)

    'Dim DgvErros = New DataGridView
    With DgvErros
        .DataSource = Bs
    End With
    Panel1.Controls.Add(DgvErros)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Configurar_GridView()
    Executar_Pesquisa()
End Sub

Private Sub ButIniciar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButIniciar.Click        
    Executar_Pesquisa()
End Sub
```

Porque, a configuração é somente 1 vez, ai você pode fazer as pesquisas e retornar esse DataTable da maneira que você desejar (com filtro por exemplo). O Botão `ButIniciar_Click`, só executa o método `Executar_Pesquisar` que o mesmo só atribui o DataTable (O DataTable que está no código é um exemplo).